# Kentico Smart Search Button with Font Awesome icon

Tags: kentico

Im very new to kentico development wise and I'm trying to work to a design given to me.

I'm currently trying to tie up the smart search web part to show as a text input with a font awesome search icon as the button (with no button text). Is there any easy way to do this? Or should I resort to making a copy of the Smart search control and extending it out?

The html designed has just

```
 <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

is there an easy way to put this into a new layout for Smart search?

Thank you Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You could use a web part before and after to wrap web part code html and class wrapper and than apply the style to the button via CSS

In most of the cases, you could benefit from custom web part layout:

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/developing-web-parts/using-custom-web-part-layouts

But smart search in this case does consist of two controls which are kinda buried inside so to insert this to control directly (CMSModules\SmartSearch\Controls\SearchDialog).

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: you can apply this by adding a custom layout for the smart search but I am not sure this will work

Solution 2: clone the web part and modify the Html as needed